# nvidia-smi command could communicate with nvidia driver microsoft azure dsvm

Tags: nvidia, azure-virtual-machine

Right after creating and starting up a data science virtual machine and connecting through ssh, I tried to use the `nvidia-smi` to see if the built-in nvidia and cuda were working property. The returned message read

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
>   driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and
>   running.

These were supposed to be part of the vm, yet when I tried to run the program I created, my local computer's default CPU was used instead of the vm's GPU. The ultimate goal of my project is to run an object detection model with the performance sped up from the my lousy 11 sec/image, so I figured I would use a vm and take advantage of its computing power. Yet it seems like this may not be the best option, so if anyone else has some advice there, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What series VM are you using? Only the N series VMs have the GPUs

Comment: I am using the Data Science Virtual Machine for Linux (Ubuntu) with the DS3_v2 SKU. Should I use something else?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are seeing is because you are using a D Series VM. Only the N series VMs have GPUs. So in order to utilize the GPU you need to select one of the following sizes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-gpu

For this size family, the vCPU (core) quota in your subscription is initially set to 0 in each region. You will need to [request a vCPU quota increase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request) for this family in an available region.

Comment: I have an N series machine, but even after installing the latest nvidia-drivers I am getting the same error. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: the same here, I have used as the base image DSVM which shall have included almost all needed, but still seems that Agent/pipeline is blocking the usage...